Stable module category of non-Frobenius algebras
It is often said that the stable module category $A-\underline{\operatorname{mod}}$ for an associative algebra $A$ is triangulated if $A$ is Frobenius (i.e. over $A$ we have projective = injective). However, as far is I understand, there is the Verdier-quotient
$$ \mathcal{D}^{\operatorname{b}}(A-\operatorname{mod}) / \mathcal{D}^{\operatorname{perf}}(A-\operatorname{mod}) \cong A-\underline{\operatorname{mod}} $$
for any associative algebra $A$.
Doesn't this mean that $A-\underline{\operatorname{mod}}$ naturally becomes a triangulated category by inheriting the triangulation from the bounded derived category regardless of $A$ being Frobenius?

Db/Dperf is called the singularity category. A nice example is $A=k[x,y]/(x^2,xy,y^2)$, where the residue field $k$ is a shift of a sum of two copies of $k$ in the singularity category. So you can write $k$ as a sum of as many pieces as you want. It's a nice exercise to find the endomorphism ring of $k$.

@JeremyRickard You are right, the question didn't make much sense. I fixed it and it should now be clear what I mean.

I don't think the isomorphism holds in general. As a matter of fact a theorem by Buchweitz asserts that the singularity category of a Gorenstein ring its equivalent to the stable category of Cohen-Macaulay modules, not of all modules.
